# Make Image fit fully inside a NavigationLInk?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftui

I have an `Image`

```
Image(img, scale:1.0, orientation:.right, label:self.label).resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode:.fit)
```

as the destination of a `NavigationLink` but it doesn't occupy the full screen: there's some margin on the left and right. How to make occupy all the horizontal space?

(However, when I remove the NavigationLink and put the `Image` by itself, it does occupy all the horizontal space. What's going on?)

---

EDIT: Here's roughly what the structure of the code looks like

```
    NavigationView{
      Spacer()
      VStack{
        NavigationLink(
          destination:{
            VStack{
              Button("btn"){}.buttonStyle(.bordered)
              VideoView(img:self.video.img)
            }
          },
          label:{
            HStack{
              Text("view").font(.title)
            }
            .frame(minWidth:300, minHeight:70).foregroundColor(.white).background(.blue).cornerRadius(12)
        })

        NavigationLink(destination:{Text("view")}, label:{
          HStack{
            Text("view").font(.title)
          }
          .frame(minWidth:300, minHeight:70).foregroundColor(.white).background(.blue).cornerRadius(12)
        })
      }  // VStack
      .navigationTitle("title")
      Spacer()
    }

struct VideoView:View{
  var img:CGImage?
  let label = Text("video") 

  var body:some View{
    if let img = img{  Image(img, scale:1.0, orientation:.right, label:self.label).resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode:.fit)  }
    else{              Color.blue  }
  }
}
```

where `VideoView` is intended to render the iPhone's camera feed as a `CGImage`, which is coming from `self.video.img`.

Comment: show us your code.  Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]? Include how you wrote the `NavigationLink` and `NavigationStack`, so that I can directly copy and paste the code into an Xcode project and reproduce the issue.

Comment: I added some code, but the actual code uses output from the iPhone's camera, and it's a lot of code.

Comment: Have you tried using `NavigationLink(destination:{ VStack(alignment: .leading) {...} ...}`

Answer (score 1):

1. I guess your device's current orientation is `landscape`
2. You can add this line below the `NavigationLink`'s `VStack {}` to ignore the horizontal edge of SafeArea.

```
.ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .horizontal)
```

Comment: I think the phone is in portrait mode (ie. vertically oriented). But this didn't work. Also tried `.ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .vertical)`, but it didn't work either. (I still upvoted for the effort of posting a reply. Thank you.)

Comment: @DiegoAlonso have you tried to change `contentMode: .fit` to `contentMode: .fill`? , maybe the `CGImage`'s width is shorter than it's height

Comment: I tried, and that kinda does work, but not exactly as expected. Now the Image occupies all the horizontal space, but for some reason I can't click the button above the Image.